# Is there an "Abelian envelope" 2-functor?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I'm looking for a notion of an Abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ "generated" by a given category $\mathcal{C}$

More precisely I need something along the following lines. Denote $\mathcal{Ab}_2$ the 2-category of Abelian categories and $\mathcal{Cat}$ the 2-category of categories. We have the forgetful 2-functor $\mathcal{F}: \mathcal{Ab}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{Cat}$. Is there an adjoint 2-functor $\mathcal{G}: \mathcal{Cat} \rightarrow \mathcal{Ab}_2$ ?

I suspect the answer is "yes" because it can be constructed along the following lines. Denote $\mathcal{Ab}$ the category of Abelian groups. For any category $\mathcal{C}$, the category $\mathcal{Hom(C, Ab)}$ is Abelian. Moreover, we have the natural functor $\mathcal{i:C \rightarrow Hom(Hom(C,Ab),Ab)}$. Thus $\mathcal{C}$ is embedded in the Abelian category $\mathcal{D:=Hom(Hom(C,Ab),Ab)}$ and we can take the Abelian category generated by $\mathcal{C}$ within $\mathcal{D}$. The result is supposed to be $\mathcal{G(C)}$

However, the only construction I managed to search up is the Karoubi envelope which generates a pseudo-Abelian category. So either my purported construction is wrong or simply not popular. Which is it?

EDIT: I realized my construction amounts to $\mathcal{G(C):=Hom(C,Ab^{op})}$. At least for small $\mathcal{C}$ this is indeed adjoint to $\mathcal{F}$, provided we interpret $\mathcal{Ab_2}$ as having *right* exact functors for 1-morphisms. Here $\mathcal{C}$ embeds by applying opposite Yoneda and taking the freely generated Abelian group.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by the 2-category of abelian categories.

Comment: I very recently had a similar idea. The main subtlety that I found was with the concept of "generated". Suppose you generate an object by two different methods, but do not generate an isomorphism between them. In the subcategory, will the two objects be isomorphic? If no, are you sure that the category is well-defined? You might have to be careful. If yes, then which isomorphism?

Secondarily, it seems that all functors in $Hom(C,Ab)$, allowed to act on the generated category, are exact. But shouldn't there be non-exact functors on the generated category sometimes?


Comment: $Hom(Ab,Ab)$ is already quite a complex category. Which subcategory is generated by the identity?

Comment: I may be barking completely up the wrong tree, but I vaguely recall the construction of some kind of Abelian envelope for an additive category (Freyd?) - is something like that along the lines you seek?

Comment: @Fernando, you are right I need to specify what counts as morphisms. I think 1-morphisms are exact functors and 2-morphisms are arbitrary natural transformations. When you say "it depends" you mean in some case it exists while in another it doesn't? Can you detail?

Comment: @Will the result is either the category of finitely generated Abelian groups or the category of all Abelian groups, depending whether you take Ab3 in your definition of an "Abelian category". It's realization as functors is via tensor product. See also my edit of the question

Comment: What's the kernel of the map $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ given by $2$? I believe it's a functor that measures two-torsion. If that's not true, how are you defining kernels of natural transformation?

Comment: Gentlemen, the answer I gave below is for the forgetful 2-functor to $Cat$ from the 2-category of abelian categories, exact functors, and natural transformations. 

Comment: @Will, the functor corresponding to the group G is tensor product with G. In particular you can take Z/2 for G

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd be inclined to go in a slightly different direction in constructing the free abelian category generated by a category. I would do it in stages:

- First construct the free $Ab$-enriched category $F_1(C)$ generated by a category $C$. This would have the same objects as $C$, but the hom $F_1(C)(a, b)$ between two objects would be the free abelian group generated by the hom $C(a, b)$ in $C$.
- Next, to any $Ab$-enriched category $C$, we may freely adjoin finite limits. We can do this by embedding $C$ into $(Ab^C)^{op}$ by the dual of the Yoneda embedding, and then cutting down to the full subcategory $F_2(C)$ of $Ab$-enriched functors which arise as limits of finite diagrams of opposites of representables $C(c, -)^{op}$ in $(Ab^C)^{op}$.
- Next, to any finitely complete $Ab$-enriched category $C$, pass to the so-called [ex/lex completion](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+and+exact+completions#the_exlex_completion_3) $F_3(C)$. The "lex" here refers to left exactness (i.e., closed under finite limits, and functors preserving such), whereas the "ex" refers to [Barr exactness](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+category) and functors preserving such.

The point is that an abelian category is precisely a Barr-exact (finitely complete) $Ab$-enriched category (see Freyd-Scedrov's Categories, Allegories, page 90, where a Barr-exact category is what they call an effective regular category). So the free abelian category generated by a category $C$ is $(F_3 \circ F_2 \circ F_1)(C)$. I did not check carefully that the ex/lex completion, as described in the nLab article, lifts from the $Set$-enriched world to the $Ab$-enriched world, but I think it's okay.

Not yet sure how this relates to your proposed construction (there are some size considerations to, er, consider), but I think the answer to your first question is 'yes'.

**Addendum:** In response to Martin's comment, and as confirmation that the description above is correct, here is a [paper](http://journals.cambridge.org/production/action/cjoGetFulltext?fulltextid=4940460) by Carboni and Magno which in the course of things constructs the free abelian category generated by an additive category: see page 300. The free abelian category on the terminal category $\mathbf{1}$ is $C_{ex}$, where $C$ is the category opposite to that of finitely generated abelian groups. There may be simpler descriptions, but I'm not prepared to say more on that now.

Comment: Thx Todd, looks very nice! I have to chew on it a bit more. In the meanwhile, can you explain what you mean by size considerations?

Comment: I meant that your $\hom(\hom(C, Ab), Ab))$ is raising a large category $Ab$ to the power of another large category $Ab^C$. This operation is illegitimate within the confines of ZFC or GBN set theory. At this point many people consider strengthening their set theory to deal with this annoyance, allowing some hierarchies of inaccessible cardinals (cf. universes), but subtleties can still arise, and I hadn't thought those through yet. 

Comment: @Todd: What about a specific example, say the abelian category which is free on one object? My first guess was the category of finitely generated abelian groups. But this seems to be the free finitely cocomplete category on one object and not every right exact functor on it is exact. So this free abelian category will be more complicated!

Comment: @Martin: yes, you're right, it is more complicated. Please see the addendum above. 

Comment: @Will: There is no embedding $C \to \mathrm{Ab}^C$. @Todd: The link is broken. What are the objects of the free abelian category on one object?

Comment: @Martin: I fixed the link. The description of the objects of $C_{ex}$ is exactly as in the nLab article as given in the third bullet point. Roughly speaking, the objects of $C_{ex/lex}$ are objects $c$ of $C$ equipped with pseudo-equivalence relations (similar to equivalence relations, but not assuming they are subobjects of $c \times c$), and morphisms are equivalence classes of arrows $c \to d$, where arrows respect the pseudo-equivalence relations, and two arrows $f, g$ are equivalent if the pair $\langle f, g \rangle: c \to d \times d$ factors through the pseudo-equivalence relation. 

Comment: Thanks Todd! I asked this question because I was hoping for a more "specific" incarnation of the objects. Well perhaps there is none ...

Comment: OK so this answer provides the adjoint 2-functor to the forgetful 2-functor from the 2-category of Abelian categories and exact functors to the 2-category of categories. The construction in the body of the question provides the adjoint 2-functor to the forgetful 2-functor from the 2-category of small Abelian categories and *right* exact functors to the 2-category of small categories. I think this settles it

Comment: If I apply this procedure to the arrow category, the image of this arrow in F2 should fail to be surjective. Yet as far as I can tell it is, since it's the dual to an injective map. What am I missing?

Comment: @Will: I'm going to guess that you were addressing me (not say Squark), that your F is the desired left adjoint $F = F_3 \circ F_2 \circ F_1$, and that F2 means $F$ applied to the arrow category. Beyond that, I'm not really sure what you're thinking or what you've calculated; I do agree that the image of the arrow ought not be an epimorphism in $F(2)$. Are you sure you applied the ex/lex completion correctly? I would be happy to try to go through this with you, but not in these damned comment boxes. I invite you to open a discussion at the nForum, where we can discuss this at length. Cheers 

Comment: My goal was to put off figuring out how to understand ex-lex completions for as long as possible. I was thereby hoping that the ex-lex completion was not the step that changed the image of the arrow from an epimorphism to a non-epimorphism. But if it is then I'll have to figure out how to understand ex-lex completions. I will get on nForum soon.

Comment: Ah, well, that *is* the step you need to consider! The reason is that the co-Yoneda embedding $C \to (Ab^C)^{op}$ preserves epis (for the same reason that the Yoneda embedding preserves monos), and this epi in $(Ab^C)^{op}$ will a fortiori remain an epi when you consider it as living in the full subcategory mentioned in step 2. 

Comment: I know I'm very late to the party: M. Adelman constructed the free abelian category over an additive category in *Abelian categories over additive ones*, J. Pure Appl. Algebra, 3(2) (1973), 103-117 in a way that doesn't have any size issues. The construction is based on Freyd's description of the category of finitely presented additive functors in *Representations of add. cats* in the '65 La Jolla proceedings. Beligiannis recently gave an extensive systematic treatment in: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.hha/1139841219  See also my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52881/ for refs.

Comment: The construction is pretty much along the lines of your answer but a more hands-on approach (only factoring out ideals in arrow categories after landing in the additive world) allows avoiding all size issues. // I forgot to mention: see section 6 in Beligianis's paper, as well as Remark 3.5. I don't remember if anything is said about 2-categorical properties of the construction but that should be manageable to decide for anyone interested. // Nice answer, by the way!

Comment: Thanks, Theo! I remember (the late) Murray Adelman well from when I was at Macquarie; it's nice to see this paper of his brought up here. I wasn't aware of it. 